# Write GADT record with constrained type

Tags: haskell, record, type-constraints, gadt

I have the following code that compiles in my program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class (Show (Data a)) => HasData (a :: *) where
    type Data a :: *

data Foo :: * -> * where
    Foo :: (HasData a) => String -> Data a -> Int -> Foo a -- bunch of args

deriving instance Show (Foo a)
```

Since the number of arguments for the `Foo` contructor can be many, I would like to write the code using record syntax, but I cannot figure out how to do this with GADT syntax (GHC deprecated datatype contexts, so I'm trying to avoid them):

```
data Foo :: * -> * where
    Foo {
        getStr :: String,
        getData :: Data a, -- want (HasData a)
        getInt :: Int
    } :: Foo a -- want (HasData a)
```

I need to constrain `a` in `Foo`'s constructor just like I did above without record syntax. How can I do this?

Comment: What's the `Data a` for? Are you adding a phantom type for some purpose, because you don't seem to have anything of type `a`, just stuff of type `Data a`. (For example, if you're just replacing a `Show` context to your constructor, that simplifies your requirements quite a bit.)

Comment: I had an unrelated issue that this solved. I'm a bit of a noob, and I couldn't figure out how to get `GADTs` to work. I added your 2 headers, for `KindSignatures`, and `GADTs`, and it now works. The pertinent error, so this comment is googleable, was: `Illegal kind signature ‘Free’
      (Use KindSignatures to allow kind signatures)`, and now I know that means to make a header in `{-# ... #-}`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can achieve this by declaring the record destructors within the type of the constructor as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Foo :: * -> * where
    Foo :: HasData a => { -- look - the context declared upfront
        getStr :: String, -- wow - function declaration in type sig!
        getData :: Data a, -- only allowed with a HasData instance
        getInt :: Int
    } -> Foo a
```

but I suspect there's an easier way of achieving what you intend to do, unless you're doing something more cunning with the type `a` than it seems.  Here's a simpler way to insist on showable data:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

data Bar a where
    Bar :: Show a => {
        getStr' :: String,
        getData' :: a, -- can Show 
        getInt' :: Int
    } -> Bar a -- have (Show a)
deriving instance Show (Bar a)
```

This way has the benefit of working for arbitrary Showable data, without making instances of the `HasData` class nor using all those compiler pragmas, but that's only of help to you if your `HasData` class was just there to make things Showable. You might have some deeper purpose I'm not seeing.

(You might consider dropping the `Show` context altogether except for where you actually use it, to simplify things more and allow you to make Functor instances. That would be simpler and wouldn't require any compiler pragmas at all. Over the years I've become fonder of keeping things general and making Functor instances.)

Comment: In the first example, what is the purpose of `HasData a => Data a`? Wouldn't the `HasData a => { record }` do the job?

Comment: I had thought that the OP wanted it, but on re-reading I see that that was just where they put the comment that they wanted that context, not specifying that they wanted to write it exactly there. (I feel I could have said that more clearly with fewer "that"s, but failed.) So basically I thought the OP wanted that, but I see now I'm probably reading in too much and will edit it out.

Comment: @Eric Thanks; one fewer extension. The RankNTypes was almost certainly not what the OP was after, and would only have caused confusing compiler errors.

Comment: @chunksOf_50 I guess I was asking if the extra constraint *meant* anything. Was it any different than with a single constraint? With RankNTypes, would the second `a` have been different from the first `a`?

Comment: Yes - you would only have been able to use a value of type `HasData a => Data a`, as in, polymorphic over all instances of `HasData`. In practice such a piece of data is hard to produce.

Comment: Perfect. Just what I wanted. It was the `-> Foo a` over `:: Foo a` that tripped me up. Thanks!

Comment: Recovering instance contexts for data members seem to work only when pattern matching on the data type (either with `(Bar _ d _)` or with record field names `Bar{ getData' = d }`). But is there any way to have this for field access functions? That is, when accessing a `Bar` `b` with an expression `(getData' b)`.